# Mixed Design ANOVA-Error: object of type 'closure' is not subsettable

Tags: r, anova

I'am running a 2X3X3 mixed ANOVA design. Ive been trying to get the student-newman Kuels function to work in R, but I keep getting the error: object of type 'closure' is not subsettable. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

```
library(ez)
library(ggplot2)
library(nlme)
library(pastecs)
library(reshape)
library(WRS)
library(GAD)
library(multcomp)
library(psych)
library(lmerTest)
CPPData <- read.table(file = "CPPdatar.csv", header=TRUE, sep = ",")
str(CPPData)
CPPData$Test<-as.factor(CPPData$Test)
CPPData$Exposure<-as.factor(CPPData$Exposure)
CPPData$Dose<-as.factor(CPPData$Dose)
CPPData$Subject<-as.factor(CPPData$Subject)
levels(CPPData$Test)<-list("Habit"=1, "Test of Conditioning"=2)
levels(CPPData$Exposure)<-list("0% HFCS CONT"=1, "50% HFCS CONT"=2, "50% HFCS INT"=3)
levels(CPPData$Dose)<-list("0 OXY"=1, "0.16 OXY"=2, "2.5 OXY"=3)
str(CPPData)
options(contrasts=c("contr.helmert", "contr.poly"))
aov1<-aov(Time~Exposure*Dose*Test+ Error(Subject/(Test)), data=CPPData)
summary(aov1)

aov2 = lme(Time~Exposure + Dose + Test, 
         random = ~1|Subject, 
         data = CPPData, 
         method = "ML")
summary(aov2)

#SNK Test
Test2<-snk.test(lm(Time~Exposure*Test*Dose, data = CPPData))
Test1<-snk.test(lm, term = Exposure*Test*Dose, among = Exposure, within = Test*Dose)
snk.test(aov2, term = "Dose:Exposure:Test", among = "Test", within = "Dose")
```

Error issues:

> ## SNK Test
>
> T**est2<-snk.test(lm(Time~Exposure*Test*Dose, data = CPPData))
>   Error in estimates(object) :** 
>     Design unbalanced! This function can only handle balanced designs.
>   **Test1<-snk.test(lm, term = Exposure*Test*Dose, among = Exposure, within = Test*Dose)**
>   Error: object of type 'closure' is not subsettable
>   **> snk.test(aov2, term = "Dose:Exposure:Test", among = "Test", within = "Dose)**
>   Error in object$model[, 2:(length(object$x) + 1)] : 
>     incorrect number of dimensions

## Dput

> dput(CPPData)
>   structure(list(Time = c(476.98, 436.94, 451.79, 514.68, 548.38, 
>   457.96, 489.99, 536.7, 517.02, 566.9, 487.15, 553.89, 527.86, 
>   580.41, 310.14, 508.84, 364.7, 456.79, 616.12, 598.43, 447.45, 
>   570.9, 520.35, 812.48, 756.92, 667.5, 603.77, 547.55, 369.2, 
>   437.6, 296.96, 568.74, 580.91, 526.19, 582.92, 568.23, 576.74, 
>   378.04, 549.38, 548.55, 492.99, 388.72, 581.75, 538.71, 511.51, 
>   895.89, 851.68, 685.85, 741.24, 738.4, 662.5, 485.32, 746.75, 
>   726.89, 638.64, 613.11, 819.65, 475.14, 599.93, 668.34, 486.99, 
>   426.26, 570.74, 482.48, 460.13, 578.08, 541.37, 465.63, 297.13, 
>   543.04, 560.89, 536.04, 419.25, 555.89, 587.75, 530.2, 619.95, 
>   778.61, 602.27, 403.74, 792.63, 815.98, 599.77, 784.28, 543.04, 
>   748.08, 610.94, 700.87, 710.38, 686.02, 735.57, 805.47, 525.02, 
>   524.86, 482.65, 278.28, 547.21, 559.23, 450.95, 579.91, 174.17, 
>   312.64, 683.02, 790.46, 422.92, 664, 435.44, 478.14, 427.43, 
>   308.31, 342.84, 517.02, 541.54, 565.73, 474.81, 522.02, 503.34, 
>   321.99, 498.16, 554.55, 527.69, 776.44, 966.47, 867.2, 846.68, 
>   554.22, 750.75, 435.44, 769.94, 561.39, 544.71, 404.24, 464.8, 
>   482.48, 550.88, 459.79, 552.05, 389.56, 361.86, 814.15, 907.41, 
>   755.92, 729.9, 945.11, 509.34, 529.86, 611.78, 675.84, 452.79, 
>   584.42, 566.4, 420.75, 465.46, 533.87, 579.58, 492.16, 521.86, 
>   565.07, 594.76, 280.95, 563.23, 537.37, 409.07, 439.44, 547.88, 
>   543.88, 496.66, 474.14, 433.43, 418.75, 541.37, 406.74, 477.98, 
>   576.58, 335.5, 405.74, 319.49, 482.15, 501, 409.07, 610.28, 667.17, 
>   560.56, 474.14, 467.3, 561.56, 718.88, 584.25, 689.52, 507.51, 
>   711.04, 520.19, 357.52, 373.04, 504, 360.86, 470.97, 489.49, 
>   397.06, 582.41, 554.05, 481.15, 776.78, 658.66, 721.55, 433.93, 
>   532.03, 625.79, 651.48, 783.78, 729.06, 828.5), Test = structure(c(1L, 
>   1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 
>   2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
>   1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
>   2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
>   1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
>   2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
>   1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 
>   1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
>   2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
>   2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
>   2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
>   1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 
>   1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
>   2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("Habit", "Test of Conditioning"), class = "factor"), 
>       Exposure = structure(c(2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
>       2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
>       2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
>       2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
>       2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
>       2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
>       2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
>       3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
>       3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
>       3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
>       3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
>       1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
>       1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
>       1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
>       1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("0% HFCS CONT", 
>       "50% HFCS CONT", "50% HFCS INT"), class = "factor"), Dose = structure(c(1L, 
>       1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
>       1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
>       2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
>       2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 
>       3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
>       3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
>       3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
>       1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
>       2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
>       3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
>       1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
>       1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
>       2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
>       3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
>       3L), .Label = c("0 OXY", "0.16 OXY", "2.5 OXY"), class = "factor"), 
>       Subject = structure(c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 
>       10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 
>       8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 16L, 17L, 18L, 19L, 
>       20L, 21L, 22L, 23L, 24L, 25L, 26L, 27L, 28L, 29L, 30L, 16L, 
>       17L, 18L, 19L, 20L, 21L, 22L, 23L, 24L, 25L, 26L, 27L, 28L, 
>       29L, 30L, 31L, 32L, 33L, 34L, 35L, 36L, 37L, 38L, 39L, 40L, 
>       41L, 42L, 43L, 44L, 45L, 46L, 31L, 32L, 33L, 34L, 35L, 36L, 
>       37L, 38L, 39L, 40L, 41L, 42L, 43L, 44L, 45L, 46L, 47L, 48L, 
>       49L, 50L, 51L, 52L, 53L, 54L, 55L, 56L, 47L, 48L, 49L, 50L, 
>       51L, 52L, 53L, 54L, 55L, 56L, 57L, 58L, 59L, 60L, 61L, 62L, 
>       63L, 64L, 65L, 57L, 58L, 59L, 60L, 61L, 62L, 63L, 64L, 65L, 
>       66L, 67L, 68L, 69L, 70L, 71L, 72L, 73L, 74L, 66L, 67L, 68L, 
>       69L, 70L, 71L, 72L, 73L, 74L, 75L, 76L, 77L, 78L, 79L, 80L, 
>       81L, 82L, 83L, 84L, 75L, 76L, 77L, 78L, 79L, 80L, 81L, 82L, 
>       83L, 84L, 85L, 86L, 87L, 88L, 89L, 90L, 91L, 92L, 93L, 94L, 
>       95L, 96L, 85L, 86L, 87L, 88L, 89L, 90L, 91L, 92L, 93L, 94L, 
>       95L, 96L, 97L, 98L, 99L, 100L, 101L, 102L, 103L, 104L, 105L, 
>       106L, 97L, 98L, 99L, 100L, 101L, 102L, 103L, 104L, 105L, 
>       106L), .Label = c("1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", 
>       "9", "10", "11", "12", "13", "14", "15", "16", "17", "18", 
>       "19", "20", "21", "22", "23", "24", "25", "26", "27", "28", 
>       "29", "30", "31", "32", "33", "34", "35", "36", "37", "38", 
>       "39", "40", "41", "42", "43", "44", "45", "46", "47", "48", 
>       "49", "50", "51", "52", "53", "54", "55", "56", "57", "58", 
>       "59", "60", "61", "62", "63", "64", "65", "66", "67", "68", 
>       "69", "70", "71", "72", "73", "74", "75", "76", "77", "78", 
>       "79", "80", "81", "82", "83", "84", "85", "86", "87", "88", 
>       "89", "90", "91", "92", "93", "94", "95", "96", "97", "98", 
>       "99", "100", "101", "102", "103", "104", "105", "106"), class = "factor")), row.names = c(NA, 
>   -212L), class = "data.frame")

Comment: Generally it is much more informative to copy the _entire_ error message. Most new users don't know how to pick out the essential parts of the error messages. It also helps to know which line of code throws the error and also to produce the results of `traceback()`. If, as it appears to have happened here, you are using non-base packages, you should start your code with `library` calls.

Comment: Also, providing your data in dput() format would help.

Comment: Ok thank you, noted, and added.

Answer (score 0):

The cause of the error you were asking about can be seen here:

> Test1 <- snk.test(lm, term = ExposureTestDose, ....

The letters "lm" are the name of a function and you gave that to a function that was expecting a data object that could be subsetted. The first call did give the `snk.test` function a data object created by `lm`, but it was stopped by code that gave a different reason.

As far as that other errors go, it appears you need some statistical advice. The `snk.test` does not appear to be designed for the type of analysis you are running. You might consider asking for help about design issues on hte CrossValidated.com site. (It's another StackExchange forum that handles statistical questions.)